# Rails: Download and authenticate files from another server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download

I have a rails application that requires file downloading. To download the files, permission is required - in this case only a logged in user can download the files. Currently, this is working as the files are on within the applications public folder. The problem is that some files are massive, and when being downloaded in turn kill the application until the download is complete.

It would be nice to separate the file from the application to prevent this (even better to host the files on a different server) but keeping the required permissions/authentication.

Is this possible? has anyone experienced this and have some adice?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Amazon S3 bucket for storing your files. Carrierwave or Paperclip gems could help you with that.

Comment: I cant use S3 - I have to use another (file server) that we have setup :(